# Cannot redeploy project to wildfly from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I start wildfly server in eclipse and go to cmd and type:

```
C:\eclipse-workspace\gg\resteasy-examples\resteasy-examples>mvn clean compile wildfly:redeploy
```

But this error occurs:

> Error executing REDEPLOY:
>   C:\eclipse-workspace\gg\resteasy-examples\resteasy-examples\target\resteasy-examples.war
>   (The system cannot find the file specified)

But project have this file in this path `/resteasy-examples/target/resteasy-examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war`.

What am I doing wrong?